# more general integral defined pointwise

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

In class the instructor heuristically introduced the Dirichlet process and wrote some things about Bayesian statistics with this, but the thing I found most interesting was that he nonchalantly defined the integral of measure valued functions in a pointwise manner.

The setup was essentially the following:

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}_X, m_X)$ be a measure space, $A$ a set, $\mathcal{M} = \{\omega: A \rightarrow \mathbb{C}: \omega \text{ satisfies some property}\}$ and $\Lambda_{\mathcal{M}}$ a reasonable $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathcal{M}$.
We say that $f:(X, \mathcal{A}_X) \rightarrow (\mathcal{M}, \Lambda_{\mathcal{M}})$ is $\textbf{noice}$ if for each $a \in A$, $f(\cdot)(a)$ is $\mathcal{A}_X$-measurable (and L^1 or positive).
Define the integral $ f \in \{\text{noice functions}\} \mapsto \int f dm_X \in \mathcal{M}$ in a pointwise fasion by $$\bigg[ \int f dm_X \bigg](a) = \int f(x)(a) dm_X(x)$$

Pointwise addition and scalar multiplication of $\{\text{noice functions}\}$ and $\mathcal{M}$ make this integral linear.

In class we had $A = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\mathcal{M} = \{\text{probability measures on } \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)\}$ or something like that.

I am wondering two things:

1. In the case that $\mathcal{M}$ is a separable Banach space, is this pointwise integral related to the Bochner integral?
2. what are some other places this pointwise integral is used?

If anyone could throw some references at me that would be much appreciated.